Are there minimal pairs distinguishing r-colored vowels from vowel+r?
I'm not a native speaker but I think I speak something close to General American with the cot-caught merger and no distinction between the strut and the comma vowels.
Whenever I hear what is supposed to be an r-colored vowel, I always just hear a vowel sound followed by an r. For example, both of the vowels in further sound like a schwa followed by an r to me. After listening for it, what I perceive to be the vowel in further does sound a bit different from the schwa in comma and strut, but if I had never heard about r-colored vowels I would have probably just assumed it was an allophone of schwa.
So my question is, are there minimal pairs distinguishing r-colored vowels from vowel +r sequences? I'm mostly interested in an example with the schwa but others would also be welcome.

The 'a' and 'e' in Comma and the boy own their schwa. Strut no, strategic yes. Further, not really - both syllables are close to urge.

How about stayer (one who stays) and stare (and its homophone, stair). Admittedly, stay doesn’t often get the -er suffix tacked on, so the example is a bit forced, but it’s not completely unnatural. A completely natural pair is shyer (more bashful) and shire.  In all such examples that have occurred to me—forced or not—the key difference is that the first element is spoken as two syllables, while the second is not.

@PaulTanenbaum Shire and shyer sound the same to me, so that works assuming I just haven't acquired the ability to tell them apart. However stayer and stare to me sound like steɪər and stɛr respectively, so that they are distinguished by the difference in eɪ vs ɛ, regardless of what's going on around the r. Correct me if I'm wrong.

You're probably not going to find many one-word minimal pairs. But how about sparring and spa ring, tapering and tape a ring. (If you didn't have the cot-caught merger, I'd add pouring and paw ring.) For these pairs, some people are going to pronounce them exactly the same, but others won't.

@PeterShor Yes, thank you, the first two pairs do sound different to me, though I'm not sure how reliable my hearing is. Do you agree with PaulTanenbaum about shire and shyer being different?

@ZsomborKiss: I pronounce shire and shyer exactly the same, but there are probably some people who pronounce them differently.

@PeterShor Is "whyer" (someone who asks "why?") a word? Because I think I would pronounce it differently from "wire".

In "further," for most speakers of General American there's no vowel before the /r/s at all--it's just a syllabic consonant. Is that what you're hearing?

@PaulTanenbaum If you want examples that are less forced, how about layer/lair and higher/hire? With yet another vowel, there's coyer/coir.

Linguists do often analyze r-colored vowels in English as just allophones. In "rhotic" accents, a vowel is always r-colored if it is followed by an /ɹ/ sound that is unambiguously in the same syllable. So there's no possible contrast in English phonotactics between something like /pɑɹt/ vs. /pɑ˞ɹt/, or /lidəɹ/ vs. /lidɚɹ/ or  /lidɚ/.
There are no minimal pairs unless you include cases where the sounds are split between syllables, and phonetic distinctions that occur only as a result of different syllabifications usually aren't treated as phonemic: compare the potential phonetic differences in vowel length, aspiration or affrication between I scream [aɪ.skɹim] and ice cream [aɪs.kʰɹim] or eyestrain [aɪ.stɹeɪn] and ice train [aɪs.t͡ʃɹeɪn].
Some analysts might prefer to treat r-colored vowels as their own phonemes, but this isn't because they contrast with vowel + r sequences. Rather, it's because for many rhotic speakers, vowel sounds that otherwise contrast with each other don't contrast before /r/: for example, the well-known Mary-merry-marry merger neutralizes original /eɹ/, /ɛɹ/, and /æɹ/. Some speakers might intuitively identify the merged vowel with either /e/ or /ɛ/, but others may not find it easy to determine which vowel phoneme occurs in these words. There can be similar ambiguity in the case of the merger between /ir/ and /ɪr/.

I suspect it’s no ‘coincidence’ that the same regions whose speakers neutralize the tense–lax distinction in E, I, O, and U before R are the same regions with a modified R approximant that takes on a retroflex, bunched, or molar articulation: perhaps all that pulling, tightening, and scrunching up of the tongue doesn’t leave enough room in the mouth to clearly distinguish both tense/close and lax/open variants from each other. I wonder whether there’s anything in the professional linguistics research literature about this hypothesis. That might make a good new question.
